# Zend Framework current route in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ladies and gentlemen,

I am working hard on a new webapplication which is based on the Zend Framework.
Almost the whole webapplication will be secured with a login(username and password).

My idea is to check if the visitor can be authenticated and if not check if the user is requesting a login route. If he is not trying to login he will be redirected to the login page.

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{  
    /**
     * Bootstrap::_initRouterRewrites()
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initRouterRewrites()
    {
        $frontController  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $this->router = $frontController->getRouter();

        $this->router->addRoute(
            'default',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/',
                                            array('controller' => 'index',
                                                  'action' => 'index'))
                     )
                     ->addRoute(
            'login',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/inloggen.html',
                                            array('controller' => 'auth',
                                                  'action' => 'login'))
        ); 
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap::_initZendSession()
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initZendSession()
    {
        // Ensure that both the session and the db resources are bootstrapped
        $this->bootstrap(array('db', 'session'));

        // Actually start the session
        Zend_Session::start();
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap::_initAuthentication()
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initAuthentication()
    {
        // Instantiate auth object
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        // Check if visitor has an identity
        if (!$auth->hasIdentity())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I use the method $this->router->getCurrrentRoute() inthe _initAuthentication method I get the following error: "Current route is not defined".

What can I do to check if the current route is login?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of bootstrapping routing has run yet. What you need here is a [FrontController Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) that hooks into the request lifecycle at the appropriate place . In your case that is probably going to be during `routeShutdown` after the routing has determined where to dispatch the request.

From http://devzone.zend.com/1692/zend-framework-mvc-request-lifecycle/:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use plugins like this in bootstrap.php:
    `protected function _initPlugins() {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Plugin_Checkaccess());
    }`

and in plugins/Checkaccess.php
   `

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{ 

    $request = $this->getRequest();
            $controllerName = strtolower($request->getControllerName());
            $actionName = strtolower($request->getActionName());

            if ('user' == $controllerName)
    {
                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('USER');

                $notLogged = array('login','register');

                if(!in_array($actionName, $notLogged) && !$session->user){
                    $request->setControllerName("index");
                    $request->setActionName("index");
                    $this->_response->setRedirect('/');
                    //$this->_response->setRedirect('/?redirectTo='.$this->_request->getRequestUri());
                }elseif(in_array($actionName, $notLogged) && $session->user){
                    $request->setControllerName("user");
                    $request->setActionName("index");
                    $this->_response->setRedirect('/home');
                }
                return;
    }
```

}
}`